# Branching of $SU\left(5\right)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

In the context of branching rules, what is a projection matrix for a subgroup. For instance, the projection matrix for the subgroup $SU\left(2\right)\times SU\left(3\right)$ of $SU\left(5\right)$ is apparently 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
What does this mean, and how do I use it?

Comment: You can use it to get the Dynkin labels of the representations under the subgroup from the Dynkin labels of the representations of the supergroup.

Comment: Is this done simply by matrix multiplication of the Dynkin label?

Comment: Yes, too long for a comment so I wrote an answer.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the projection matrix to find out into which representations a given representation branches. In your example SU(5)$\to$SU(3)$\times$SU(2), the 5-plet has the weights with Dynkin labels
$$ (1, 0, 0, 0),\quad(-1, 1, 0, 0),\quad(0, -1, 1, 0),\quad(0, 0, -1, 1),\quad(0, 0, 
  0, -1)\;.$$
They get mapped under $P$, i.e. by multiplying them by the $P$ matrix, to 
$$ (0| 1, 0),\quad (1| 0, 0),\quad (0| -1, 1),\quad (-1| 0, 0),\quad(0| 0, -1).$$
where I separated the SU(2) part from the SU(3) part by a bar ``|''. After reordering, this becomes
$$ \{ (1| 0, 0),(-1| 0, 0)\}\quad\text{and}\quad\{(0| 1, 0),(0| -1, 1),(0| 0, -1)\}\;,$$
i.e. an SU(2) doublet plus an SU(3) triplet, as expected.

Comment: How did you get the weights' Dynkin labels? Also, shouldn't there be four weights, since the rank is four?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley A 5-plet has clearly 5 weights. See e.g. [here](http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/texall.pdf) how to compute the weight diagram of an arbitrary representation, and [here](http://renatofonseca.net/susyno/group_theory_tutorial.php) for a Mathematica package that does such things.